# Alert box in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing my project about scanner. So if i have finished to scan bardcode, the alert box will appear and show the ingredients of food products. But i have found the problem in alert box, it appeared but it only show native alert box. 
Can someone help, how to change style in alert box.

My codes are below:

```
var localJSONFile= "db/product.json";
$.getJSON(localJSONFile)
        .success(function(data, status, xhr){
            $.each(data, function(i, product){
                if(result.text == product.barcode){
                    alert( "name: " + product.name + "\n"  + 
                           "barcode: " + product.barcode + "\n" +
                           "status: " +product.status + "\n" +
                           "E-code: " + product.e_code + "\n" +
                           "Ingredients: " + product.ingredients + "\n" +
                           "Country: " +  product.country + "\n" +
                           product.image
                         );
                }
            });
         })
```

Comment: You'll want to use something other than `alert()` if you want to style it.

Comment: do u have some idea how to style it maybe ?

Comment: It is impossible, you can not style the native alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot style an alert box, there are alternative projects out there however, SweetAlerts being my personal favourite, that make alert boxes look good

Answer (score 1):

Alert box are native styled, cannot be modified, rather get rid of alert and make your own simple alert pop up to display information.

Comment: did u mean with jquery ui ?

Comment: There are tons of lightweight plugins available, you can refer to one here http://jatinmarwah.github.io/Overlay-Modal-Window/

Comment: @AndrewTristan, it is pretty trivial to create one of your own

Answer (score 1):

Alert box cannot be customized.They are mostly used by developers for testing purposes.

However, you can use a dialog. Here's the reference: [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)